# Can we add custom CSS to team site masterpage without activating publishing feature?

Tags: 2013, css, team-sites

I want to apply custom CSS to a team site Seattle master page in SharePoint 2013. Is there any way available to do this without activating publishing feature?

I tried adding `<link>` tag in masterpage, but it doesn't take any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload your css to the master page gallery or site assest folder, you can create a folder in your master page gallery and upload your CSS file there either manually or using a module in Visual Studio. Then you can refernce it using :

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/YourSiteFolder/YourCSSFile.css %&gt;"
      runat="server"
      after="corev15.css"/>
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, Should I add above line in Seattle.html?

Comment: Before that you need to have your custom css file in master page gallery

Comment: Yes I have added CSS file in master page gallary. But when I add above line in Seattle.html and Preview, it throws me error that "SharePoint can't parse this file, most likely because of an incorrectly formatted SharePoint snippet."

Comment: I added below line in HTML file and it worked
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom Style/CustomCSS.css %&gt;"  runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>-->